# Removing stopwords from char array

Tags: c++, arrays, cpu-word

I'm trying to make a function that removes a pre-defined word (a char array) from a char array. It sort of works and removes the word from a char array, but it only works if the words are separated by spaces. I want to make it so it removes the word from a group of words not separated by spaces, but I don't know how. I'm stuck on this and would appreciate any help.

```
int i, j = 0, k = 0, count = 0;
char str[1024] = "thisisthestringtobealtered."; // works using spaces
char key[256] = "the"; // I want "the" to be removed in str
char str1[10][20];

void removeWordFromString(){

    /* Converts the string into 2D array */
    for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (str[i] == ' ') {
            str1[k][j] = '\0';
            k++;
            j = 0;
        }
        else {
            str1[k][j] = str[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    str1[k][j] = '\0';

    /* Compares the string with given word */
    for (i = 0; i < k + 1; i++) {
        if (strcmp(str1[i], key) == 0) {
            for (j = i; j < k + 1; j++)
                strcpy(str1[j], str1[j + 1]);
            k--;
        }

    }


    for (i = 0; i < k + 1; i++) {
        printf("%s ", str1[i]);
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're coding in C++? And fix the title.

Comment: As you sassily insist. And I guess it's for the most C with some C++ in there.

Comment: I was refering to *"string without namespaces"* typo. Nothing sassy about that.

Comment: I would tag this question with "C" as it does not use any C++ - it doesn't even use anything beyond C89. Might even compile with a K&R compiler.

Comment: @dascandy Everything in the code is legal `C++`. It should be tagged with whatever the compiler language is the OP is using to compile it with.

Comment: Note that to start, you cannot convert it into a 2D array because that assumes there are spaces to split it on. You'll have to find a completely different approach to the code given instead of modifying it in place. I would suggest starting with the original inputs & replacing "the " (with a space), using your own code to do it, without splitting the string first.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution for this problem would be using strncmp().
This function allows you to compare substrings.

Start like this:

Compare the initial string with the key with num = length of the key.

If it does match cut the substring out

move one character into the initial string and compare again.

Loop until you have less characters in the initial string left than your key is long.

Answer (score 0):

```
void removeWordFromString(){    
        /* Converts the string into 2D array */
        int ckey=0;
        i=0;
        while(str[i] != '\0')
        {
                while(str[i] == key[ckey] && key[ckey] != '\0')
                {
                        str1[k][j] = str[i];
                        j++;
                        i++;
                        ckey++;
                }
                if ( key[ckey] == '\0' )
                {
                        str1[k][j-strlen(key)] = '\0';
                        k++;
                        j = 0;
                        ckey=0;
                }
                else{
                        str1[k][j] = str[i];
                        j++;
                        i++;
                        ckey=0;
                }
        }
        str1[k][j] = '\0';

        for (i = 0; i < k + 1; i++) {
                    printf("%s ", str1[i]);
        }
}
```

Replace the above function in your code.

Comment: A good answer generally points out what the code in the answer is doing and why it needed to change, not just a block of code with no explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for a readable algorithm.

```
Find the place in the string where the key occurs.
while I can find such a place, then 
    remove this occurrence
    look for the next.
```

Or in code:

```
char str[1024] = "thisisthestringtobealtered."; // works using spaces
char key[256] = "the"; // I want "the" to be removed in str

void removeWordFromString(){
    char* p = strstr(str, key);
    while (p) {
        // Move from end of key, to start of key, the number of characters we can 
        // find after the key, plus a null terminator. Memmove because the string 
        // overlaps itself.
        memmove(p, p + strlen(key), strlen(p) - strlen(key) + 1);
        p = strstr(str, key);
    }
}
```

Note that this solution is very code-size-efficient and probably too clever to pass as first-year programmer code. I hope this makes it useful to you for learning while ineligible for handing in as a code exercise solution :-)